# AJAX showing Success and Error Messages at the same time

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var useride = $("#userid").val();
        var category = $("#selectedcategory option:selected").text();
        var manufacturer = $("#selectedmanufacturer option:selected").text();
        var processor = $("#selectedprocessor option:selected").text();
        var model = $("#model").val();
        var ram = $("#ram").val();
        var serialNo = $("#serialNo").val();
        var serviceTagNo = $("#serviceTagNo").val();
        var supplier = $("#selectedsupplier option:selected").text();
        var date_indent = $("#date_indent").val();
        var date_approval = $("#date_approval").val();
        var date_issuance = $("#date_issuance").val();
        var date_purchase = $("#date_purchase").val();
        var vendor = $("#vendor").val();
        var approved_by = $("#approved_by").val();
        var warranty_expiry_date = $("#date_expiry").val();
        var price = $("#price").val();
        var recommended_by = $("#section option:selected").text();

        var markup = "<tr><td></td><td>" + category + "</td><td>" +
            manufacturer + "</td><td>" + processor + "</td><td>" + model +
            "</td><td>" + ram + "</td><td>" + serialNo + "</td><td>" +
            serviceTagNo + "</td><td>" + supplier + "</td><td>" +
            date_purchase + "</td><td>" + vendor + "</td><td>" +
            warranty_expiry_date + "</td><td>" + price + "</td><td>" + recommended_by + "</td>             </tr>";
        // ajax method starting here.
        //Current request reference; can be used else where
        var request;
        /* attach a submit handler to the form */
        $("#myForm").submit(function (event) {
            // abort any pending request
            if (request) {
                request.abort();
            }
            /* stop form from submitting normally */
            event.preventDefault();
            /*clear result div*/
            $("#result").html('');
            /* get some values from elements on the page: */
            var values = $(this).serialize();
            /* Send the data using post and put the results in a div */
            request = $.ajax({
                url: "/test/get_time.htm",
                type: "post",
                data: values,
                async:true,
                success: function () {
                    alert("submitted successfully");
                    $("table tbody").append(markup);
                    $('table tbody tr').each(function (idx) {
                        $(this).children(":eq(0)").html(idx);
                    });
                },
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert("Same Serial No or Same Service Tag number already exists in the DB");
                    console.log(xhr);
                }
            });
        });
    }
</script>
```

The problem is that on successful submission, the code display success message, but even if once i get error message because of trying to duplicate submission of the same  data, the next time on every  successful submission of data, the error message of duplicate entry is also shown . I can't figure out the reason.

Comment: try to use `click` instead of `submit`

Comment: seems if you duplicate your request you are trying to cancel pending request with ` request.abort();` so your first request gonna fail with canceled error and second one will succeed.

Comment: Looks like `request.abort();` is the reason, I think. Instead of it, you can use `return;` to cancel current request.